# C/C++ malloc a block of memory and then use different portion for different, arbitrary types

Tags: c++, c, malloc

There is certainly little reason for me to do it. Let's just say I am bored and wanted to explore if this is possible. :)

Supposed I want to implement the node of a linked list. I can certainly do

```
struct Node {
  int val; 
  Node *prev, *next; 
}
```

But let's say I am bored and I want to do something like malloc-ing a chunk of memory for a node, then arbitrarily decide the first portion is the pointer to a previous node, and the middle portion is the value, the last portion is the pointer to the next node. Is it do-able?

I tried something like this and it fails to run.

```
*second = first
```

failed specifically.

```
void** createNewNode(int val) {
    void** p = (void**)malloc(sizeof(int) + 2*sizeof(void*));
    *(p+1) = &val; 
}

void connectTwoNodes(void** first, void** second) {
    *(first+2) = second; 
    cout << "first assigned!" << endl;
    *second = first;
    cout << "second assigned!" << endl;
}

int main() {

    void** p1 = createNewNode(1);
    void** p2 = createNewNode(2);
    cout << "both created!" << endl;
    connectTwoNodes(p1, p2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is tricky because you can't be sure that all the addresses will be correctly alligned for the data types.

Comment: You can't indirect through void pointers. You have to case them to the appropriate type

Comment: Instead of using assignments, you can use `memcpy` to copy from one pointer to another.

Comment: `struct Node {  std::string val;   Node *prev, *next; };`  Now all your malloc's cause UB (undefined behavior) once you actually use the Node..

Comment: "...then arbitrarily decide the first portion is the pointer to a previous node, and the middle portion is the value, the last portion is the pointer to the next node". In other words, you want to treat it as a new struct with elements prev, val, and next, in that order. So then you could just define that new struct rearranged_node, cast the original *node to a *rearranged_node, then copy the members (using temps since you are overwriting in place).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the general idea is possible but your code has a lot of mistakes:

- `p+1` and `first + 2` is illegal since you cannot do point arithmetic on a `void *`. You have to convert the pointer to point to a complete type before doing the arithmetic.
- `*second` is illegal because `void` is an incomplete type.
- `sizeof(void *)` may be different to `sizeof(Node *)`
- If you ever intended to write `struct Node *ptr = p1;` , that actually would not work due to structure padding. Similarly, trying to access the `Node *` pointers by casting their address might fail due to alignment. You'd have to `memcpy` the pointers out of the storage.

In general, you can read and write whatever you like into `malloc`'d space subject to alignment and the strict aliasing rule. Paraphrased, the latter says that if you write some stuff into the memory, then you can't read it out as a different type (unless that different type is a character type). But you can overwrite it.

I can't figure out what you are trying to do in `connectTwoNodes`. But code to do something similar in C might be:

```
void *createNewNode(int val) 
{
    char *cp = malloc(sizeof(int) + 2 * sizeof(void *));
    void *null_node = NULL;

    memcpy(cp, &val, sizeof val);
    memcpy(cp + sizeof val, &null_node, sizeof null_node);
    memcpy(cp + sizeof val + sizeof null_node, &null_node, sizeof null_node);
    return cp;
}

void connectTwoNodes(void* first, void* second) 
{
    char *c1 = first, *c2 = second;

    // first->next = second
    memcpy(c1 + sizeof(int) + sizeof(void*), &second, sizeof second);

    // second->prev = first
    memcpy(c2 + sizeof(int), &first, sizeof first);
}

int main()
{
    void* p1 = createNewNode(1);
    void* p2 = createNewNode(2);
    connectTwoNodes(p1, p2);  
}
```

**tl;dr:** Don't do this

Comment: You want to use placement new to have C++ construct your objects for you. In the case of plain structs this isn't strictly necessary, but it is the C++ way to do it and the only way to do what you describe with proper classes. http://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#placement-new

Comment: Thanks. one more question, why do you use char* type in your connectTwoNodes()?

Comment: @CodeNoob So that `+` can be used on it

Comment: @Ben my answer is for C.  This technique would only work in C++ for trivially copyable types anyway; placement new doesn't fix that.

Answer (score 0):

To add to what others have said, you also can't assume that the size of a struct is the same as the sum of the sizes of its fields.